# Can't start Visual Studio Code installed with snap

Tags: 16.04, xfce, snap, ide, visual-studio-code

I've installed Visual Studio Code with snap on Ubuntu 16.04 but it won't start or give me an error message.  How do I debug it?

```
$ sudo snap install code --classic
$ sudo reboot
$ snap list
Name  Version   Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
code  51b0b281  6     stable    vscodeâœ“     classic
core  16-2.38   6673  stable    canonicalâœ“  core
$ snap run code
$ sudo snap run code
[sudo] password: 
You are trying to start vscode as a super user which is not recommended. If you 
really want to, you must specify an alternate user data directory using the --user-data-dir argument.
$ snap run code
$
$ ps -elf | grep code
0 S gradesc+  3945  1699  0  80   0 -  3556 pipe_w 15:23 pts/8    00:00:00 grep --color=auto code
$ ps -elf | grep snap
4 S root      1151     1  0  80   0 - 324508 -     14:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
0 S gradesc+  3947  1699  0  80   0 -  3556 pipe_w 15:24 pts/8    00:00:00 grep --color=auto snap
```

Nothing comes up on my screen.  I'm VNCing into the server which is using an xfce GUI.